# Linked table of contents (toc) in md using rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I use **rmarkdown** package to make an Rmd into an md I can include a toc via:

```
  md_document:
    toc: true
```

But they are not linked.  Now I can do this manually after using `render` using this function I created:

```
rmarkdown::render("README.Rmd", "all") 

md_toc <- function(path = {(x <- dir())[tools::file_ext(x) == "md"]}){
    x <- suppressWarnings(readLines(path))
    inds <- 1:(which(!grepl("^\\s*-", x))[1] - 1)
    temp <- gsub("(^[ -]+)(.+)", "\\1", x[inds])
    content <- gsub("^[ -]+", "", x[inds])
    x[inds] <- sprintf("%s[%s](#%s)", temp, content, 
        gsub("[;/?:@&=+$,]", "", gsub("\\s", "-", tolower(content))))
    cat(paste(x, collapse = "\n"), file = path)
}

md_toc()
```

It works by reading the file back in and manually inserting the links with the form `[Section 1](#section-1)`.

Is there a better approach to make the md toc link to the sections?

I have this as a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/trinker/testing_Rmd) if it's easier but here's a MWE Rmd:

````
---
title: "testing_Rmd"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: journal
    number_sections: true
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
  md_document:
    toc: true      
---


# Section 1

Stuff

# Section 2

More Stuff

## Random Stuff A

1 + 2

## Random Stuff B

```{r}
1 + 2
```

# Conclusion
````

Answer (score 1):

Working from [a post](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2012-11/msg00018.html) in the pandoc discussion group, would something
like this work for you?

Assume the source is testTOC.Rmd...

````
```{r mdTOC, echo=FALSE}
mdTOC <- grepl("markdown", knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") )
```

```{r, engine='bash', results='asis',echo=FALSE, eval=mdTOC}
# toc-template.txt is somewhere in the path and only contains a single line:: $toc$
pandoc --template=toc-template.txt --toc --to html --from markdown testTOC.Rmd |\
pandoc --to markdown --from html
```
````

Outputs::

```
-   [Section 1](#section-1)
-   [Section 2](#section-2)
    -   [Random Stuff A](#random-stuff-a)
    -   [Random Stuff B](#random-stuff-b)
-   [Conclusion](#conclusion)
```

So you'd want to set `toc: false` in the header YAML to not repeat it.